# Clojure's (read-line) returns nil; does not prompt

Tags: clojure

I'm working on my first proper Clojure program--a chess game. I have the following:

```
(defn human-move [board]
  (board-utils/print-board board)
  (print "Enter your move, like this: 'E7 E5' ...")
  (loop [raw-move (terminal-input)] ;;(read-line)]
    (println "I just received" raw-move)
    (if (re-matches #"[A-H][1-8]\s[A-H][1-8]" raw-move)
      (parse-move raw-move)
      (do
        (println "Invalid format! There should be a letter, number, space, letter, and final number.")
        (print "Try again: ")
        (recur (read-line))))))
```

Note the place where `read-line` is commented out and replaced by `terminal-input`. `read-line` was giving me a NullPointerException, so for diagnostic purposes:

```
(defn terminal-input []
  (println "input")
  (let [whatnot (read-line)]
    (println "received" whatnot)
    whatnot))
```

Then, when I call `human-move`.

```
...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| P | P | P | P | P | P | P | P |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| R | N | B | Q | K | B | N | R |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Enter your move, like this: 'E7 E5' ...input
received nil
I just received nil
```

I never got a chance to type something in as input. Were this Java, I'd start playing little games with the garbage collector (calling `Scanner.next()`, for instance), but with Clojure I didn't know what to do besides putting the `(flush)` in there.

For what it's worth, this is with SLIME.

---

I also tried to have `terminal-input` provide dummy data, and learned that I'm apparently using `loop`/`recur` incorrectly.  I haven't investigated it super-thoroughly though, since I've been distracted by the `read-line` issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work now with swank-clojure 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT if you wrap the call to read-line in swank.core/with-read-line-support like this

```
(with-read-line-support (println "a line from Emacs:" (read-line))
```

https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure/commit/f4a1eebc4d34f2ff473c4e5350f889ec356f5168

Comment: Btw, I've also added read-from-minibuffer and y-or-n-p support.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I look forward to having a reason to try this.

Answer (score 8):

`read-line` doesn't work in SLIME. I can't find the discussion thread about this, but it's true.

Comment: Thud. Um...is there some kind of workaround? Would it be worth playing games with Java's Scanner class?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790889/clojure-lein-read-line-stdin-woes - a bit old, but probably still helpful.

Comment: They say: "But I just pushed a bugfix to lein repl, and now read-line works in the repl for me. Let me know if it works for you in the latest 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT"

So in project.clj, I changed `:dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure "1.2.1"]]` to `...swank-clojure "1.4.0-SNAPSHOT`. Then I ran `lein deps && lein swank`, reconnected with Emacs, and still have the problem.

For what it's worth:

`$ lein version`

`Leiningen 1.5.2 on Java 1.6.0_24 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`


I'm not really sure what to *do* with the telnet business they mentioned.

I guess I should talk to the lein mailing list?

Comment: That thread is about a sort-of unrelated issued with reading from stdin with lein repl. AFAIC, reading from an input stream connected to the Slime repl is simply not implemented swank-clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me:

```
(swank.core/with-read-line-support
   (read-line))
```