# Clojure REPL Unable to resolve symbol

Tags: clojure, runtimeexception

When executing this function from lein run, the program executes as expected. But I am trying out atom.io's proto-repl package and when I call the function using the proto-repl, it gives a "CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: can-vote in this context."
Here is my function:

```
(defn can-vote
  []
   (println "Enter age: ")
   (let [age (read-line)]
    (let [new-age (read-string age)]
     (if (< new-age 18) (println "Not old enough")))
      (println "Yay! You can vote")))
```

Comment: What namespace is this function defined in?

Comment: (ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class)) 
So I highlight the entire function in the left-pane of the editor, the proto-repl on the right updates to the clojure-noob core namespace, but when I try calling the function thereafter to watch it execute, it throws this exception.

Comment: If I paste the function directly into the REPL it seems to execute but does not allow me to enter any text at the prompt when calling the (can-vote) function

Comment: That's a different problem, see here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707558/clojure-read-line-doesnt-wait-for-input

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When your repl starts, it likely puts you in the `user` namespace.  You either need to move to your `clojure-noob.core` namespace or call it with the fully qualified symbol.

**If you want to switch namespaces**

```
(ns clojure-noob.core) ;; switch to the correct namespace
(can-vote) ;; call the function
```

**If you want to call it with the fully qualified symbol from the user namespace**

```
(require 'clojure-noob.core) ;; first require the namespace
(clojure-noob.core/can-vote) ;; call the fully qualified function
```

You can read much more about namespaces and calling functions from other namespaces and libraries [here](https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html).

Comment: Thanks. 2 consecutive Clojure tutorials declined to share this info and I was blocked.